# common legends for multiple dojo charts

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting, legend-properties

I'm trying to plot two charts having same legends(selectable legends) but different plotting values using **DOJO charting**. so i want to keep the legends as common for both the charts. So that if i unselected a legend it would effect to the both charts.

For clear reference please find my attachment [dojo chart example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJJgw.jpg)

```
new SelectableLegend({
                            chart: chart,
                            horizontal: true
                        }, legdiv);
                    });
```

above is the code used to generate legends.

Please help me to make it.

Comment: One legend group can be assigned to one chart only , so what you are asking for is not possible

Comment: Is there any way to uncheck a legend on buttonclick?